# C buggy program

Tags: c

I don't know why this program says that 5 was not found in the array when clearly there is a 5 in the array. Also, rarely it won't output any `printf` message. Apart from this, it correctly identifies if the specified number is present.

Thank you for your time.

Number 5 present but wrong output message and no output message displayed-

[image: Number 5 present but wrong output message and no output message displayed]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void print_array(int a[], int num_elements);
int findNumber(int array[], int array_size, int value);


void main()
{
    srand(time(NULL)); //Produce random numbers
    int randomNums[10]; //Array of 1000 ints
    int index, value;


    //Populate the array with random ints from 1 to 10
    int i; //Merely for looping purposes
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        randomNums[i] = rand() % 10 + 1; //Random range from 1 to 10
    }

    print_array(randomNums, 10);
    findNumber(randomNums, 10, 5);
}




void print_array(int anarray[], int num_elements)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < num_elements; i++)
    {
        printf("Element %d: %d \n", i, anarray[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int findNumber(int array[], int array_size, int value)
{

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
    {
        if(array[i] == value)
        {
            //Number found
            printf("%d found at element %d \n", value, i);
            break;
        }
        if(array[i] == array_size && array[i] != value)
        {
            //Number not found
            printf("%d not found \n", value);
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your `findNumber` function is not returning anything. Pay attention to your compiler warnings.

Comment: Your `findNumber` is not returning anything. What's the point in checking the value of array with the size the array? In both cases you do `break`, the loop most certainly runs only once.

Comment: If `array_size` is `10` and `value is `5`, the second `if` tests if `array[i] == 10 && array[i] != 5`.   That is only ever true if `array[i] == 10` (i.e. if there is a value of `10` in the array).

Answer (score 2):

In the loop in `findNumber`, the statement:

```
if(array[i] == array_size && array[i] != value)
```

causes the loop to print a message and stop if `array[i]` equals `array_size`. In this, `array[i]` is an element in the array. You likely intended to test `i == array_size` instead. However, that is also incorrect, because, inside the loop, `i` will never equal `array_size`. The controlling condition in the `for` statement is `i < array_size`, which means, if `i` is not less than `array_size`, the loop will not do another iteration.

You need to both correct the test to `i == array_size` and put it after the loop, not in the loop.

Additionally, remove the `array[i] != value` from that `if` statement. If `i` equals `array_size`, it will refer to an element outside the array.